# World Map with Country Borders in the Oceans

Tags: borders

Is there a world map that depicts the borders including territorial waters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a a layer in [Google maps](http://www.justmagic.com/GM-GE.html#Anchor-6/-49575), note that link is somewhat dated, also there is an interactive web map at [MarineRegions.org.](http://www.marineregions.org/eezmapper.php)

Answer (score 4):

This image from [CoastalWiki.org](http://www.coastalwiki.org) is produced using data from MarineRegions.org.

[MarineRegions.org](http://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php) offer this and other datasets as GIS data (shp, kml), interactive maps, and static images (though none as pretty as the image below).

[image]